# Display an AJAX JSON result inline on click of a link dynamically within a loop in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a JSP page that has multiple dynamic links on it within a forEach loop. I use an AJAX call to the backend by passing a parameter and get the corresponding results in JSON format. Now I want to display these results just under each section corresponding to this link( and then if we click on the same link again, it needs to hide the table). After a lot of searching, I am able to display a table row under each section using the below code, but it displays the same data under each section. How do I display data corresponding to each link under its own section, please? I guess some kind of indexing needs to be done, but don't know how.

Edit: Added 2 screenshots of how it was before[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2X04.jpg) and is after [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCxV5.jpg) clicking the link

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var tableId=this.id;
 $(".a_link").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  alert(href);
      $.getJSON(href, function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, item) {
            var $tr = $('<tr/>');
            $tr.append($('<td/>').html('<a href= "{URL}/dashboard?id='+item.projectKey+'">'+item.projectKey+'</a>'));
            $('tr.keys').before($tr);

        });
    });
   });
});

</script>
```

```html
<title>Projects Totals View</title>
</head>


<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <core:forEach items="${model.totals}" var="total" varStatus="loop">
     <br/>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="left"><h4><strong>Product: <a class ="a_link" href="/expand?group=${total.projectGroup}"> <core:out value="${total.projectGroup}"/></a></strong></h4></div>        
    </div>

    <table class="table_content">
        <tr>
            <th>Total Count</th>
            <th>Total Percent</th>
            <th>Partial Percent</th>
            <th>Total TC</th>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><core:out value="${total.count}"/></td>
            <td><core:out value="${total.percent}"/></td>
            <td><core:out value="${total.partialPercent}"/></td>
            <td><core:out value="${total.dy}"/>d <core:out value="${total.hr}"/>h <core:out value="${total.mn}"/>m</td>            
        </tr>
        <tr class="keys"><td></td></tr>
    </table>

</core:forEach>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I made this working:
 For each of the  link, I gave an id="${loop.index}" and based on this id, an inner table will be created under each section within the  tag

Code snippet below:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.a_link', function(e){
  $(this).data("clicked", !$(this).data("clicked"));
  e.preventDefault();
  var clickId = $(this).attr('id');
  var host = $('#host').val();
  // the below if-else is for toggling the data (show and hide which is actually add and remove here)
  if ($(this).data("clicked")) {
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      $.getJSON(href, function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, item) {
              var $tr = $('<table id="innerTable"/><tr/>');
              $tr.append($('<td/>').html('<a href= "'+host+'/dashboard?id='+item.projectKey+'">'+item.projectKey+'</a>'));
              $('tr.keys-'+clickId).append($tr);
          });
      });
  }else{
      $('tr.keys-'+clickId).children('table').each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
      });
  }

});
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <core:forEach items="${model.totals}" var="total" varStatus="loop">
     <br/>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="left"><h4><strong>Product: <a id="${loop.index}" class ="a_link" href="/expand?group=${total.projectGroup}"> <core:out value="${total.projectGroup}"/></a></strong></h4></div>        
    </div>

    <table class="table_content">
        <tr>
            <th>Total Count</th>
            <th>Total Percent</th>
            <th>Partial Percent</th>
            <th>Total TC</th>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><core:out value="${total.count}"/></td>
            <td><core:out value="${total.percent}"/></td>
            <td><core:out value="${total.partialPercent}"/></td>
            <td><core:out value="${total.dy}"/>d <core:out value="${total.hr}"/>h <core:out value="${total.mn}"/>m</td>            
        </tr>
        <tr class="keys-${loop.index}"></tr>
    </table>

</core:forEach>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the expected output. I have removed the jsp code for trying the same. `Please refrain using id (for table, div) which is inside loop`. I have used class for the same. Please find the HTML code snippet below,

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="left"><h4><strong>Product: <a class ="a_link" href="#"> product 1</a></strong></h4></div>  
</div>
 <table class="table_content">
    <tr>
        <th>Total Count</th>
        <th>Total Percent</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test value1</td>
        <td>Test value2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="keys"><td></td></tr>
</table>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"><h4><strong>Product: <a class ="a_link" href="#"> product 2</a></strong></h4></div>   
</div>
 <table class="table_content">
    <tr>
        <th>Total Count</th>
        <th>Total Percent</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test value3</td>
        <td>Test value4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="keys"><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And respective jQuery part,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".a_link").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var tableNo = $('a').index($(this));
     $('table:eq('+tableNo+') tr.keys').after('<td>'+ 'vinoth'+'</td>');
    });
});
```

Since I cannot mock the ajax part and json data, I have skipped those code and using some static data. You can replace the code with your ajax and json data. You can find the static **[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/oggbj4q3/3/)** for your reference. Let me know if this helps.

Cheers..!

Comment: Sorry, I did not add that the dynamically constructed <td> will have {item.projectKey} as links ( edited in the jquery snippet). So when I try      
    var tableNo = $('a').index($(this));                                                                                     the tableNo has different values depending on the no.of items passed from the backend. Do you think there is another way of doing it? Thanks for answering :)

Comment: May I ask why you said refrain from using id? I have actually found a way to display each section under its own by using the  id. Should I not do it?

Comment: Really I don't understand your point. What's `tableNo` returning? When I tested from fiddle, it's starts from 0 and goes on. In simple terms if we click on the 0th index link, we need to modify/add it in the 0th index table.

Comment: `ID` should be unique in overall dom model. Which is like name of your's. Think what if you have 20 *ljs* in your class? ID attribute should be a unique identification of particular element, since you're inside loop it's a best practice to use class.

Comment: I have used the id as the index value of the loop as in the code snippet.